# Button works in Main XML but not in other XMLs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-button

My button is supposed to redirect me back to my main activity layout but for some reason it is not doing anything. But the thing is, my buttons on my main activity layout works when going to other layouts but not vice versa.

In my XML file, I have a button with id 'scanbuttons' like so,

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/scanbuttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="scan" />
```

And the code in my .java file.

```
public class ScanForm extends AppCompatActivity {                                                                                        

    Button scanButton;                                                                                                               

    @Override                                                                         
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                              
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                           
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_form);                                  


        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanbuttons);                          

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                    
            @Override                                                                 
            public void onClick(View view) {                                          
                Intent scan = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(scan);     }   
});
```

No error is to be found, just that clicking the button does not bring me to the desired intent location which is MainActivity in this case.

Comment: where is your button ?

Comment: Can you show the XML as well ?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post. Sorry about that

Comment: Is your button in activity_scan_form xml?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right thing? That is, are you certain the `Activity` that's not responding is actually `ScanForm`? Is that `<Button>` the only thing in the `activity_scan_form` layout? Is there possibly another `View` that's overlapping it? Is there any visual feedback when you click it?

Comment: Hi, yes I've checked that I am in the correct file, the button is indeed in activity_scan_form.xml and it is the only thing there (for testing purposes). It is the only view in the java code and there is a visual feedback when I click it (greys out when clicked) just that nothing happens. Could this be a hardware issue?

Comment: Nah, it's likely something simple, but there's not enough info here to pin it down. When I asked "are you certain the `Activity` that's not responding is actually `ScanForm`?", I meant, at runtime, are you sure that's the `Activity` that's appearing on-screen, with the non-responsive `Button`? Are you possibly getting it mixed up with another `Activity`? That is, are you sure you're calling something like `startActivity(new Intent(..., ScanForm.class));`? Is there possibly any code in `MainActivity` that's causing it to finish immediately, so it just doesn't look like it's starting at all?

Comment: Hi mike thanks for your reply! Im positive, because at startup I have this main screen with a button that works that leads to ScanForm. The button in ScanForm however should lead back to the main screen but it doesnt. The layout has a different look so I can tell which one is main and which one is scanform.

Comment: Is there any code in `MainActivity` that's possibly causing it to finish immediately after starting it from `ScanForm`? Alternatively, is there any code in `MainActivity` that's immediately starting `ScanForm` again, on top of `MainActivity`? What happens if you hit the back button a few times after clicking your `scanButton`? Are you seeing extra Activities? As another test, what happens if you call `finish()` in `scanButton`'s `OnClickListener`, instead of `startActivity()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as below,

```
public class ScanForm extends AppCompatActivity {                                                                                        

    Button scanButton;                                                                                                               

    @Override                                                                         
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                              
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                           
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_form);                                  

        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanbuttons);                          

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                    
            @Override                                                                 
            public void onClick(View view) {                                          
                Intent scan = new Intent(ScanForm.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(scan);     
        }   
});
```

I hope this helps. It's basic intent. You just have to provide the context from you want to navigate to another context. So, try replacing your getApplicationcontext() with your activity context.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but same issue button is not doing anything. Nothing happens when I click, logcat does not say anything too.